# WPF Bind control to DataView

Tags: wpf, binding

I am having a LOT of trouble trying to bind my controls to a data source.  I tried binding to XML document. That worked, but lots of issues when I tried to refresh the XML document itself and have it update the UI.

My newest try is to bind my controls to a DataView, which seems simple.  I have a sample app I found here on StackOverflow, which does this:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

        DataTable dataTable = GetTable();
        Binding dataTableBinding = new Binding();
        dataTableBinding.Source = dataTable;
        dataTableBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("Rows[0][MyTextColumn]");
        txtMyTextColumnDataTable.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, dataTableBinding);

        DataView dataView = dataTable.DefaultView;
        Binding dataViewBinding = new Binding();
        dataViewBinding.Source = dataView;
        dataViewBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("[0][MyTextColumn]");
        txtMyTextColumnDataView.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, dataViewBinding);
    }
```

This works perfectly, right out of the box.  I added a button whose code updates the value in the data table, and the textbox immediately reflects the new value when I click that button.

I tried this in my VB.Net project, like this:

```
    dim plcData As DataTable = GetTable()
    dim plcView As DataView = plcData.DefaultView
    dim plcBinding As Binding = New Binding
    plcBinding.Source = plcView
    plcBinding.Path = New PropertyPath("(0)(conveyor_plc_data_Main_FeedCarousel_caroAngle)")
    Me.tb.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, plcBinding)
```

And it doesn't work.  It will not update my UI control.
In both cases, GetTable builds a 1-row DataTable with sample data.  In my VB project, tb is a TextBlock on my MainWindow.

In the VB project, I can interrupt my code and query the particular data column in the Immediate window, and the proper value is there.  It just won't update into my control.

This seems like a very simple thing to do.  I am quite new to WPF, and can't see what is wrong with my code.  Eventually I would like to define the binding in my XAML, but can't figure out how to do this.  At this point, a code-behind setting of the binding would be ok.  I will have many controls to be bound to many data columns.

Can anybody tell me what obvious thing I'm missing here?

Comment: Does the VB version work if you use the same property path as C#? `plcBinding.Path = New PropertyPath("[0][conveyor_plc_data_Main_FeedCarousel_caroAngle]")`

Comment: OMG, it's that stupidly simple??? In my defense, I thought it was the proper VB syntax, which normally uses parens instead of brackets.

Comment: When I query the value in Immediate window, the brackets don't work: ?plcView[0]["conveyor_plc_data_Main_FeedCarousel_caroAngle"]
Identifier expected.

Comment: The `PropertyPath` class has no way of knowing whether you're using VB or C#, so it can't change its syntax based on the language it's called from.

Comment: The immediate window will use the syntax from the current language, so you'll need to use the VB syntax there.

Comment: Thanks @RichardDeeming. BTW, any idea how to do it in XAML?  I Tried: Text="{Binding Source=plcView, Path=[0][conveyor_plc_data_Main_FeedCarousel_caroAngle]}" but doesn't work.

Comment: It depends where `plcView` is defined. If it's a property of the `DataContext`, try: `{Binding Path=plcView[0][conveyor_plc_data_Main_FeedCarousel_caroAngle]}`

Comment: It is declared in MainWindow code, set in MainWindow_Initialized. Don't quite know how to set it up in XAML, because must load the datatable in code.

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms742451.aspx), the syntax for the `PropertyPath` class only accepts C#-style indexers.

> Single Indexer on the Immediate Object as Data Context:
>
> ```
> <Binding Path="[key]" .../>
> ```

The class has no way to change its syntax based on the calling language.

---

**EDIT**
To set the binding in XAML when the `DataView` is created in the code-behind, expose the view as a property:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty plcViewProperty 
   = DependencyProperty.Register("plcView", typeof(System.Data.DataView), 
   typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(null));

public System.Data.DataView plcView
{
   get { return (System.Data.DataView)GetValue(plcViewProperty); }
   set { SetValue(plcViewProperty, value); }
}

private void MainWindow_Initialized(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
   plcView = GetTable().DefaultView;
}
```

Then in your XAML:

```
<Window x:Name="TheWindow" ...>
   ...
   Text="{Binding ElementName=TheWindow,
      Path=plcView[0][conveyor_plc_data_Main_FeedCarousel_caroAngle]}"
```

Comment: Before I saw this, I tried `Me.DataContext = plcView` in MainWindow_Initialized, then `Text="{Binding Path=[0][conveyor_plc_data_Main_FeedCarousel_caroAngle]}"` (without the DataView name) in TextBox's XAML. Works without a property being declared. Still can't declare the DC in XAML, but that's ok.

Comment: Now the big question: Can I, in code, delete the row in plcView, then add a new row 0 (with new values), and the binding will automatically cause all values to update?

Comment: I added a property because I wasn't sure whether you already had a `DataContext` set. If you change the data in the row, or replace the row, you'll need to raise a suitable `PropertyChanged` event for the property. Try setting the `DataContext` to `null` and then back to the `DefaultView`.

Comment: But if I don't use a property, I guess I don't need a PropertyChanged event? Then when I want to replace the row, can I delete the row, then add the new row, then all is good, or do I then need to then clear and reset the DataContext?  Thanks SO much...

Comment: I'm new to this forum. Don't know how to mark yours as answer, and I have no reputation at all so can't vote it up. But you da man Richard! Thanks, you helped me achieve progress on this very important app.

Comment: The [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) is a good place to start: "When you have decided which answer is the most helpful to you, mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer." :)

Comment: May I know what's the need to create a dependency property here? I believe dependency properties should ideally be used for controls that can have visual appearance. The DataView already implements IBindingList interface which allows it to notify the WPF infrastructure if a new DataRow is added or an existing one is removed.